# How to use Perl `sort` and `pairwise` if I already have variables `$a` and `$b`

Tags: arrays, perl, scope

I want to write a Perl subroutine like this:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{pairwise};
sub multiply {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    return [ pairwise {$a * $b} @$a, @$b ];
}
```

(multiplication is just an example, I'm gonna do something else)

However, this gives me nonsensical results, because Perl gets confused and tries to use the outer `$a` and `$b` instead of the list items.

If I try this code in a REPL (such as `reply`):

```
0> use List::MoreUtils qw{pairwise};
1> my $a = [1, 2, 3];
…
2> my $b = [3, 2, 1];
…
3> pairwise {$a * $b} @$a, @$b;
Can't use lexical $a or $b in pairwise code block at reply input line 1.
4> sort {$a <=> $b} @$a;
"my $a" used in sort comparison at reply input line 1.
"my $b" used in sort comparison at reply input line 1.
$res[2] = [
  1,
  3,
  2
]
```

So far, my solution has been replacing `my ($a, $b) = @_;` with `my ($a_, $b_) = @_;` (i.e. renaming the troublesome variables).

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Don't call your variables `$a` and `$b` which are awful variable names in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

Well, first off - `$a` is an awful variable name. Why are you doing that? Single letters are almost always a bad choice, and just about ok if it's just an iterator or some other simple use.

So the *solution* would be 'don't call them `$a` and `$b`'.

I mean, if you *really* don't want to use a different name:

```
sub multiply {
   return [ pairwise { $a * $b } @{$_[0]}, @{$_[1]} ];
}
```

But what you've done is really highlighted why namespace clashes are a bad idea, and thus using `$a` and `$b` in your code as actual variables is asking for trouble.

I don't think there's a way to make it work they way you're trying to, and even if you could - you'd end up with some code that's really confusing.

I mean, something like this *should* work:

```
sub multiply {
   my ( $a, $b ) = @_;
   return [ pairwise { $::a * $::b } @$a, @$b ];
}
```

Because then you're explicitly using the package `$a` and `$b` not the lexical one. But note - that won't work the same way if they're imported from another package, and it just generally gets messy.

But it's pretty filthy. [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) tells you outright that you shouldn't do it:

> $a
>
> $b
>
> Special package variables when using sort(), see sort. Because of this specialness $a and $b don't need to be declared (using use vars , or our()) even when using the strict 'vars' pragma. Don't lexicalize them with my $a or my $b if you want to be able to use them in the sort() comparison block or function.

And that's before you get into the territory of 'single letter variable names are pretty much always a bad idea'.

So seriously. Is:

```
my ( $first, $second ) = @_;
```

Actually so bad?

Comment: `$a` isn't a super-global like `$_`, so `$::a` will only work if the call to `pairwise` is in `main`. Test: `perl -MData::Dumper -we'package Pkg; use Data::Dumper; use List::MoreUtils qw{pairwise}; sub multiply {
   my ( $a, $b ) = @_;
   return [ pairwise { $::a * $::b } @$a, @$b ];
} print(Dumper(multiply([2,3,4],[4,3,2])));'`

Answer (score 4):

`pairwise` sets the `$a` and `$b` found in its caller's package, so you could use fully qualified variable names.

Assuming this code is in package `main`,

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{pairwise};
sub multiply {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    return [ pairwise { $main::a * $main::b } @$a, @$b ];
}
```

---

Alternatively, `our` creates a lexical variable that is aliased to the current package's variable with the same name, and it will override the `my` declaration since the most recent lexical-variable declaration wins out.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{pairwise};
sub multiply {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    return [ pairwise { our $a * our $b } @$a, @$b ];
}
```

---

The second approach is obviously much less fragile than the first one, but you know what would be even less fragile? Not declaring `$a` and `$b` as lexical vars in the first place! :) It would be far simpler just to use different variables. Even `$A` and `$B` or `$x` and `$y` would be better.